# How to customize controller's response with specific exits from helper?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, helper

I'm using Sails.js v1.2.2 and organizing my controllers with single file rather than action 2. Also I use helpers in my controllers.

Now when the helper triggers some exit other than success, the controller will automatically response with the specific format like

{
    "cause": {
        "name": "Exception",
        "code": "ParameterError",
        "exit": "ParameterError",
        "traceRef": {},
        "raw": {
            "msg": "My custom message"
        }
    },
    "isOperational": true,
    "code": "ParameterError",
    "exit": "ParameterError",
    "traceRef": {},
    "raw": {
        "msg": "My custom message"
    }
}

How can I custom the response data when the helper exits no-success?

I've tried custom exits in helper file, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

U can use sails generator.  `sails generate response myCustomHandler`. Check [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/custom-responses) for custom responses.

Then just try catch helper like in example:

```
try {
  await sails.helpers.test()
    .intercept({ code: 'test' }, ()=>{ return new Error('err1') })
} catch (e) {

  if (e.message === 'err1') {
    return res.badRequest('Test Bad request')
  } else if (e.code === 'ParameterError') {
    return res.serverError('Parameter Error Message in server error')
  } else {
    return res.myCustomHandler('Test Custom handler')
  }
```

This is an example with intercept u can use to do more custom stuff. Just ignore it if u don't need that. If u use actions2, then return with this statement. `return this.res.myCustomHandler('Some error')`.
In myCustomHandler.js file, u can format error. Check this [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/custom-responses).